# (py2neo) How to check if a relationship exists?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Suppose I have the following code:

```
    link = neo4j.Path(this_node,"friends",friend_node) #create a link between 2 nodes
    link.create(graph_db) #add the link aka the 'path' to the database
```

But let's say later I call:

```
link2 = neo4j.Path(friend_node,"friends",this_node)
link2.create_or_fail(graph_db)
```

Basically, `link.create_or_fail()` would be a function that either adds the link2 path to the database or it fails if a path already exists.

In this case, when I called `link = neo4j.Path(this_node,"friends",friend_node)` , I already created a path between `this_node` and `friend_node` so `link2.create_or_fail(graph_db)` should do nothing. Is such a function possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I have done for that is use the following function:

```
def create_or_fail(graph_db, start_node, end_node, relationship):
    if len(list(graph_db.match(start_node=start_node, end_node=end_node, rel_type=relationship))) > 0:
        print "Relationship already exists"
        return None
    return graph_db.create((start_node, relationship, end_node))
```

The method `graph_db.match()` looks for the relationship with the given filters.

The following [link](http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/graphs_nodes_relationships/) helped me out to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have landed here searching for newer version pf py2neo then you can call `match_one` to check the relationship:

`graph.match(nodes = nodeList, r_type = rtype)`

where *nodeList* is a sequence of nodes for the relationship and *rtype* is relationship type.